After "Git: Open Changes" how to jump to non-changes view of file
This used to work in the past. If I did Cmd Shift P and selected Git: Open Changes while a editor for current file was open, it would go to the changes for that file. And in the past, calling Git: Open Changes while the changes was open, would jump back to the editor for the current file, so I can continuing deving like normal.
However it no longer works. Is there any command that will see the currently open file for the current Git: Open Changes view, and open that file?
